# Sqlite select return 1 row after insert

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have a problem after select from sql. I send to updateRow an NSArray of 5 objects. After update (I did 5 times addRow), I get just one of them back on getGroupsByUserId.

Here is my code:

```
+(BOOL)createUserTable:(sqlite3*)database{
    char* errormsg;

NSString* sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %@ (%@ TEXT PRIMARY KEY, %@ TEXT)",USER_GROUPS_TABLE,USER_ID,GROUP_ID];
int res = sqlite3_exec(database, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errormsg);
if(res != SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"ERROR: failed creating USERS-GROUPS table");
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}

+(void)updateRow:(sqlite3*)database rowToUpdate:(NSArray*)rowToUpdate{
    for (UserGroup* ug in rowToUpdate) {
        [UsersGroupsRelationShipSql addRow:database userId:ug.userId groupId:ug.groupId ];
        NSLog(@"update Row %@ %@", ug.userId, ug.groupId);
    }
}

+(void)addRow:(sqlite3*)database userId:(NSString*)userId groupId:(NSString*)groupId{
    NSLog(@"addRow: '%@', '%@'", userId, groupId);
    sqlite3_stmt *statment;
    NSString* query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO %@ (%@,%@) values (?,?);",USER_GROUPS_TABLE,USER_ID,GROUP_ID];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,[query UTF8String],-1,&statment,nil) == SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_bind_text(statment, 1, [userId UTF8String],-1,NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statment, 2, [groupId UTF8String],-1,NULL);
        if(sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_DONE){
            sqlite3_finalize(statment);
            return;
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statment);
    NSLog(@"ERROR: addRowToTable failed %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}



+(NSMutableArray*)getGroupsByUserId:(sqlite3*)database userId:(NSString*)userId{
    NSLog(@"getGroupsByUserId: '%@'", userId);
    NSMutableArray* data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    sqlite3_stmt *statment;
    NSString* query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from USERS_GROUPS WHERE %@ = %@;", USER_ID,userId];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,[query UTF8String],-1,&statment,nil) == SQLITE_OK){
        while(sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_ROW){
            NSString* usId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statment,0)];
            NSString* grId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(statment,1)];
            NSLog(@" row: '%@', '%@'", usId, grId);
            UserGroup* ug = [[UserGroup alloc] init:usId groupId:grId];
            [data addObject:ug];
        }
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"ERROR: getGroupsByUserId failed %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        sqlite3_finalize(statment);
        return nil;
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statment);
    return data;
}
```

Debug result:

```
2016-01-13 11:30:11.901 MaverickApp[7196:142637] userId Logged = 1
2016-01-13 11:30:11.919 MaverickApp[7196:142637] Groups tab was loaded
2016-01-13 11:30:11.920 MaverickApp[7196:142675] getGroupsByUserId: userId = 1 from Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:11.922 MaverickApp[7196:142675]  get row: userId = 1, groupId = 2  from Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:11.927 MaverickApp[7196:142675] Returned groupsByUser from parse from date 2016-01-13 09:24:11 +0000
2016-01-13 11:30:11.931 MaverickApp[7196:142637] Groups tab was loaded
2016-01-13 11:30:11.932 MaverickApp[7196:142684] getGroupsByUserId: userId = 1 from Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:11.935 MaverickApp[7196:142684]  get row: userId = 1, groupId = 2  from Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:11.937 MaverickApp[7196:142684] Returned groupsByUser from parse from date 2016-01-13 09:24:11 +0000
2016-01-13 11:30:12.121 MaverickApp[7196:142675] Returned row: groupId 1 userId 6
2016-01-13 11:30:12.121 MaverickApp[7196:142675] Returned 1 groups for userId = 1 from parse
2016-01-13 11:30:12.122 MaverickApp[7196:142675] data 1
2016-01-13 11:30:12.122 MaverickApp[7196:142675] update Row: userId = 1 groupId = 6 in Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:12.123 MaverickApp[7196:142675] add Row: userId = 1 groupId = 6 in Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:12.127 MaverickApp[7196:142675] addRow done
2016-01-13 11:30:12.128 MaverickApp[7196:142675] getGroupsByUserId: userId = 1 from Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:12.129 MaverickApp[7196:142675]  get row: userId = 1, groupId = 6  from Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:12.129 MaverickApp[7196:142675] Group id number 6 for userId 1
2016-01-13 11:30:12.142 MaverickApp[7196:142675] getGroup: groupId = 6 from Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:12.143 MaverickApp[7196:142675] getGroup: groupId = 6  from Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:12.145 MaverickApp[7196:142675] Returned groups from parse from date 2016-01-13 09:24:14 +0000
2016-01-13 11:30:12.504 MaverickApp[7196:142684] Returned row: groupId 1 userId 6
2016-01-13 11:30:12.505 MaverickApp[7196:142684] Returned 1 groups for userId = 1 from parse
2016-01-13 11:30:12.505 MaverickApp[7196:142684] data 1
2016-01-13 11:30:12.506 MaverickApp[7196:142684] update Row: userId = 1 groupId = 6 in Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:12.506 MaverickApp[7196:142684] add Row: userId = 1 groupId = 6 in Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:12.509 MaverickApp[7196:142684] addRow done
2016-01-13 11:30:12.511 MaverickApp[7196:142684] getGroupsByUserId: userId = 1 from Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:12.511 MaverickApp[7196:142684]  get row: userId = 1, groupId = 6  from Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:12.512 MaverickApp[7196:142684] Group id number 6 for userId 1
2016-01-13 11:30:12.512 MaverickApp[7196:142684] getGroup: groupId = 6 from Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:12.512 MaverickApp[7196:142684] getGroup: groupId = 6  from Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:12.513 MaverickApp[7196:142684] Returned groups from parse from date 2016-01-13 09:24:14 +0000
2016-01-13 11:30:12.824 MaverickApp[7196:142675] Returned 3 groups from parse
2016-01-13 11:30:12.825 MaverickApp[7196:142675] addGroup: groupId = 2 in Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:12.828 MaverickApp[7196:142675] addGroup done
2016-01-13 11:30:12.828 MaverickApp[7196:142675] addGroup: groupId = 6 in Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:12.830 MaverickApp[7196:142675] addGroup done
2016-01-13 11:30:12.830 MaverickApp[7196:142675] addGroup: groupId = 8 in Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:12.832 MaverickApp[7196:142675] addGroup done
2016-01-13 11:30:12.833 MaverickApp[7196:142675] getGroup: groupId = 6 from Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:12.834 MaverickApp[7196:142675] getGroup: groupId = 6  from Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:13.138 MaverickApp[7196:142684] Returned 3 groups from parse
2016-01-13 11:30:13.138 MaverickApp[7196:142684] addGroup: groupId = 2 in Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:13.142 MaverickApp[7196:142684] addGroup done
2016-01-13 11:30:13.142 MaverickApp[7196:142684] addGroup: groupId = 6 in Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:13.144 MaverickApp[7196:142684] addGroup done
2016-01-13 11:30:13.144 MaverickApp[7196:142684] addGroup: groupId = 8 in Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:13.145 MaverickApp[7196:142684] addGroup done
2016-01-13 11:30:13.146 MaverickApp[7196:142684] getGroup: groupId = 6 from Sql
2016-01-13 11:30:13.147 MaverickApp[7196:142684] getGroup: groupId = 6  from Sql
```

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest using `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` for your `sqlite3_bind_text` calls.

Comment: I'd also suggest checking success or value of `sqlite3_step`, e.g., `int rc; while((rc = sqlite3_step(statment)) == SQLITE_ROW ) { ... }; if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) { ... }`

Comment: If you're still having problems, you might want to edit code to log (a) values inserted; (b) the values retrieved by `getGroupsByUserId`. And then insert what showed up in the log when you ran the code, inserting the five userid/group values and selecting them back out.

Comment: Where to add the check, i like the idea. Can you edit my answer and make all the changes??? I am a little green and I see that you know about this @Rob

Comment: For example, in first line of `addRow` add `NSLog(@"addRow: '%@', '%@'", userId, groupId);`. And in `getGroupsByUserId` add `NSLog(@"getGroupsByUserId: '%@'", userId);`. And in `while` loop of `getGroupsByUserId`, add `NSLog(@"  row: '%@', '%@', usId, grId);`.

Comment: @Rob Look my edit of debug results

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of problems:

1. You are using `INSERT OR REPLACE`. If the primary key of your table was just the userid field, you'd see the behavior your describe. Double check the primary key for this table.
2. Make sure the database is not in the bundle, but rather is in some updatable location, such as Documents folder or the like.
3. In your original `getGroupsByUserId`, I don't see how that would work at all, because you were not using `?` placeholder, nor were you using quotes around the string literal. I would have thought that would have generated an error.

   I'd suggest doing using `?` placeholder for the `userId` and then use `sqlite3_bind_text` for that value in the `WHERE` clause. But you've now changed the code in your answer (without telling us whether the behavior changed or not).

Comment: if i change where %@ = ? and use sqlite3_bind_text. Where i add this line and what i do to get the each column parameter? Look my edit

Comment: How can i debug the sql file to ensure again to have 5 objects (I can see them on debug anyway)

Comment: Re `?` placeholder, yep that looks good (though, again, I'd use `SQLITE_TRANSIENT`). Re debugging, see my comment above.

Comment: @Jdoe - BTW, before you changed the `?` were you really not getting any error? That seems exceedingly unlikely. And now that you have changed it, does it change the behavior of the app? (As an aside, in the future, I'd discourage you from changing your code in your question because it then makes the answers confusing/meaningless to future readers. When you edit a question, add changes to the end of the question, rather than changing the question itself.)

Comment: I changed my question because I can't paste code here and show you. The results are the same results and I didn't get any error before I've changed the ?. This is very strange and I think that we should open the sqlTable to the the 5 objects. Maybe I see them on debug but they didn't really in the sql db? I downloaded the sqlbrowser but I don't know how to search the file and maybe is worthless

Comment: @Jdoe - Did you see my revised answer? Did you check what the key is on that table (my first point in my revised answer)?

Comment: The key is the userId, the same key I've used to get the group. Look my edit